# Why could C# overload two methods with the same params as long as one of them has default param?

Tags: c#, overloading, default-value

I recently noticed that C# compiler allows methods overloads like the following:

```
    public static string foo(string a, bool x = false)
    {
        return "a";
    }
    public static string foo(string a)
    {
        return "b";
    }
```

As far as I tested, it always returns "b" as long as the second param is not given, which makes sense. However, I think the compiler really should not allow this type of overloading. May I ask the reason why this feature is designed like this rather than giving an error by compiler?

Comment: So is this question or a statement? This is actually quite an in depth topic called overload resolution in the C# ECMA specification, which can happen at compile or runtime. Saying something should work differently is fine (maybe you have completely thought about this in every conceivable way so much so they should hire you for the Roslyn and runtime team), however its nothing we can help you with

Comment: `However, I think the compiler really should not allow this type of overloading.` Why do you think that?

Comment: `Why could C# overload two methods with the same params as long as one of them has default param?` The obvious answer is they _don't_ have the same parameters.

Comment: you probably are seeing this kind of warning: `Method with optional parameter is hidden by overload.`

Comment: [Consider rephrasing the "why" question into a "what" question.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/323382/5133585)

Comment: Agree; as it stands this question is essentially "what we're Microsoft thinking when.." which, unless @EricLippert happens to notice it  stands a low chance of getting an answer because most people here aren't responsible for writing the c# compiler (even Eric isn't any more) and cannot speak to the thought processes and design meeting contents of those who are. Such questions are typically off topic; you'd be better off asking it on github where the compiler is developed and discussed

Comment: @TheGeneral Thanks for guiding me to the topic. I edited the post to end with a question to make it clear this is a question. Maybe there are good reasons to allow this overloading in C#, but I feel it is weird as a C# user. If a programming language feature works against developers' expectation, it's a potential problem anyways.

Comment: @mjwills I agree with developers should not write methods like this, but it is my expectation to prevent it via compiler for a strongly typed static programming language.

Comment: @bearxy39 it might have been as simple as, when they were at the "*overload resolution committee*" meeting and spun the "*overload resolution feature wheel of fortune*" it landed on, "*meh... just leave it*". :) The fact is, its exceedingly hard to find paper trails to this type of thing and what the options they had when deciding these types of features and why they actually chose what they chose.

Comment: @DorLugasi-Gal Just double checked, no such a warning in my VS error list.

Comment: But only you(as far as I know) as a problem with it. If you don't like it, you can install sonar cube / R# / some other analyzer that picks it up , or even not use c#.. we can't change c# to suit you, we don't really know how to change you to suit c# so all we can really do is point out that you can make c# warn you that you've done it and you can make whatever adjustments you need to..

Comment: @DorLugasi-Gal you have resharper installed?

Comment: @CaiusJard actually I'm working on Rider

Comment: @CaiusJard I believe most C# developers do not know this feature, and most developers have good principle for not having code like this this.  I occasionally noticed this problem in a big legacy C# file. It is difficult for me to believe most C# developers would agree this feature.  I've used 10+ programming languages and everyone has their own problems. It is a surprise to know that C# does not suit me just because I think it has one problem.

Comment: I guess then your option is to install an analyzer that will look for this and tell you about it. In a large codebase it could be invaluable; if it saves a developer a day then it's worth the business ponying up for eg resharper. I don't know if other analyzers contain anything but if they don't, you could suggest it to eg Roslynator team. Also, your question seems to be a duplicate of https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/344128/c-possible-method-name-conflicts-with-optional-parameters-why-it-is-not-forbi

Comment: BTW, I found Microsoft did claim the overload resolution in their documents: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/named-and-optional-arguments#overload-resolution

Answer (score 1):

While questions like this are fundamentally impossible to answer, since it is impossible to guess the language designers intentions, I might make a guess.

Optional arguments are handled by transforming the code to inject the argument to the call site. So

```
public static void Test(int a = 42){...}

...
Test();
```

would be transformed to to

```
public static void Test(int a){...}

...
Test(42);
```

by the compiler. From this point on the regular overload resolution can run without conflicts. Why was it designed this way? I have no idea, but common reasons for non intuitive features is backward compatibility or language compatibility.

For this reason it is important to be very careful using optional arguments in public APIs. Since the user of the library will use the default value from the version of the API it was compiled against. Not the version it is running against.

Answer (score 1):

I can't speak to why this is part of the design so much as simply explain why you see which overload is favored in your testing.

If you look at the [reference documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/named-and-optional-arguments#overload-resolution), you'll note the following three bullets to describe overload resolution:

- A method, indexer, or constructor is a candidate for execution if each of its parameters either is optional or corresponds, by name or by position, to a single argument in the calling statement, and that argument can be converted to the type of the parameter.
- If more than one candidate is found, overload resolution rules for preferred conversions are applied to the arguments that are explicitly specified. Omitted arguments for optional parameters are ignored.
- If two candidates are judged to be equally good, preference goes to a candidate that doesn't have optional parameters for which arguments were omitted in the call. Overload resolution generally prefers candidates that have fewer parameters.

I would assert that in your test, bullet #3 is most applicable to your observations - because you omit the second argument and either method is equally good, resolution favors your second method and you see "b" returned.